# How can I view the mobile version of a webpage in Google Chrome for Desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, mobile-url

I want to test the mobile version of a website using Google Chrome for Desktop.

Usually I'm able to load mobile sites by prefixing `m.` before the URL, but trying to load [`m.superuser.com`](https://m.superuser.com/) or [`m.github.com`](https://m.github.com) just results in a "***Site cannot be reached***" error.

**How can I test the mobile version of a website in Chrome for Desktop?**

Comment: Clicking the "mobile" link at the bottom of any page works fine for me.

Comment: It's already been [asked and answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104458/switch-to-mobile-site-on-standard-browser) ;p

Comment: @DavidPostill You're linking to a meta question which asks about how to run _Stack Exchange_ in mobile version on desktop browser. I am pretty much sure that OP is asking how to run _any_ website in that way. That are pretty much two completely different cases.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use Google Chrome's developer tools to request the mobile version of a website:

---

1. Open Chrome's developer tools with <kbd>F12</kbd>.
2. Click the '*Toggle device toolbar*' button  to turn Device Mode on or off. (Icon is blue when Device Mode is on).

   [image: Enabling device mode]
3. (Optional) Select which mobile device you want to simulate with the '*Viewport controls*'.

   [image: Viewport controls]
4. Refresh the webpage with device mode enabled to allow the mobile version to load.

   [image: Viewing mobile site for Super User]

#### Sources

- [Google Developers - Simulate Mobile Devices with Device Mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/)
- [Google Developers - Test Responsive and Device-specific Viewports](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports)
- [Reddit - How do I force Chrome (desktop) to load the mobile version of a website instead of the desktop version?](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/33wj65/how_do_i_force_chrome_desktop_to_load_the_mobile/)

Comment: @steven-m-vascellaro for some reason the `responsive` dropdown is not visible in my chrome...any idea?

Comment: @vardin - you need to click the button indicated by the giant red arrow in the first screenshot to get the responsive dropdown to appear.

Comment: This only seems like a partial solution. Some components like select multiple are rendered differently on desktop vs mobile even if you enable responsiveness or any of the other options there. Is there a way to emulate it fully?