# Force Google Chrome to always work in mobile version for certain pages

Tags: google-chrome, mobile-url

I pretty much like and enjoy Wikipedia in mobile version, when browsing it on desktop PC. I would like to see it that way anytime.

Is there any Google Chrome's configuration switch or maybe a plugin that would allow user to define a group of webpages or URLs that are always requested as mobile version?

I am aware that this [is possible using Developers Tools](https://superuser.com/a/1214830/156554), but that is not what I am asking about. Regular webpage browsing with Dev Tools open doesn't seems like a good idea. I am looking for something like a kind of white-list where I could put URLs that would be always opened that way.

If there's a similar solution to other browser (i.e. Firefox, Opera, Edge), please, share as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly may have other factors underneath but, generally speaking, many sites, Wikipedia included, simply redirect the User to a different version of their website if on mobile. Here, a random example from my recent history list (don't question :p):

PC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma

Mobile: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma

This redirection occurs after a condition is satisfied and this condition is based upon the **User-Agent**, one of the many [Request Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header) with a (long) string of characters the browser sends to the server of a site which tells a bit of the User visiting the Page. E.g:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36

With this, the Wikipedia, for example, knows I'm visiting them from a Windows x64 PC using Google Chrome.

If the condition that triggers the redirection is based on the User-Agent, if you modify it manually you can pretend to be using different settings.

For Google Chrome, I've tested [User-Agent Switcher for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg) which allowed me with a few clicks on the icon added near the address bar to change my User-Agent to a mobile one. Among the available options, you can find different browsers and even mobile Operating Systems (Android, iOS and Windows Phone).

By clicking, for example in **Android** and then picking **Android KitKat** my User-Agent string became:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; Nexus 4 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.114 Mobile Safari/537.36

There are different methods of validating if a User-Agent is from someone on mobile or not, but the most common is that **Mobile** expression near the end. Two clicks, the page reloads and I'm sent to Wikipedia Mobile.

By default, you'll have to manually define the User-Agent you want to use and it's a global change, meaning it'll apply to any subsequent tabs/windows you open but if that's a burden you can also make this change individually, by domain.

In its options panel, under **Permanent Spoof list** you can set *wikipedia.org* as domain and pick one of the mobile options from the dropdown and from then on, every time you visit a Wikipedia page you'll be redirected to the mobile version.

Although it's not the same extension, I've found [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher-revived/) for Firefox. It has a nicer UI in which you define everything in-place, Mobile/Desktop Device and an Operating System. It also allows the change to be per domain or just specific URLs, by defining them as a comma-separated list in the field below the icons.

Comment: Same here, as in WebApps. Perfect answer. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't work for Instagram :c Their site is broken on non-mobile, but switching to mobile by only spoofing a user-agent doesn't work. And their URL string has no distinction between desktop and mobile versions either.