# How can a Chrome user with a small screen resolution make websites (like StackOverflow) more usable?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, resolution

I am using PowerToys to split my ultrascreen into multiple panels. One of my panels has a resolution of 1024x1080, which I guess is "small".

A browser in this panel is fairly painful to use. Here's for example stack overflow:

[image]

The left and right panels take up almost all of the real estate. What would be great is a way to collapse those panels so that the content has more space. Is this possible?

Another example is google.com, which, while the main content is visible, the google apps button is far away in the corner, leading to an ugly horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may emulate a device with a small screen, such as the iPad.
All websites that are designed to work with small screens will then act accordingly.

Here are a couple of Chrome extensions that might help:

- [User-Agent Switcher for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg/related)
- [Mobile View Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mobile-view-switcher/bmhfelbhbkeoldaiphchjibggnoodpcj?hl=en)
- The following post is highly upvoted but didn't work for me:
  [How can I view the mobile version of a webpage in Google Chrome for Desktop?](https://superuser.com/questions/1214829/how-can-i-view-the-mobile-version-of-a-webpage-in-google-chrome-for-desktop)

Comment: I tried the the last option that didnt work for you and it worked for me.

Comment: The computer gods are capricious...