# Desktop Chrome stuck displaying mobile site

Tags: google-chrome

[crutchfield.com](http://crutchfield.com) displays its mobile site to me no matter what I do. I've tried resetting all the caches and deleting all the cookies and all that business, but nothing changed. The steps [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1214829/how-can-i-view-the-mobile-version-of-a-webpage-in-google-chrome-for-desktop) also didn't work for me - toggling that device mode setting does change the rendered size of the page, but it's still always the mobile site.

Interestingly, loading the page in an incognito tab *also* shows the mobile version, so I'm not sure it's related to any state on my machine at all.

Safari shows the page correctly.

macOS Big Sur 11.1
Chrome 88.0.4324.96

Comment: Have you tried to clear cookies and site data?

Comment: Try also to clear cache data. Do you have this same problem with other browsers than Chrome?

Comment: Yes to cookies/cache/site data, as I described in the question. And Safari on the same machine works fine.

Comment: If it's only Chrome, you could uninstall it (save bookmarks), clear out all its folders, then reinstall. Also try in incognito mode.

Comment: What internet service provider do you use? I wonder if they are miscategorizing your traffic as mobile due to your IP address. (As to why that would only affect Chrome not Safari, we'd need to know more about their browser fingerprinting, but it's still an avenue worth considering.)

Comment: AT&T Fiber. I think it works correctly on other machines; I’ll check.

Comment: Many sites act automatically by __providing a layout appropriate to the resolution__ of the connecting device. Sometimes rearranging elements, other times, if you resize the window to less than a certain limit (chosen by the single site designer), they switch from computer to phone layout. Could this be your case?  Try with mobile requiring expressly a Desktop site layout, maybe they have only the mobile layout.  BTW I have problem connecting to that site (time out errors) so I could not check it.

Comment: Some information about your target site: https://www.websitesvalues.com/search/crutchfield.com/
It appears to accept http and https connections. I keep having connection timeout issues, but it might be local. Maybe they're just undergoing a site update.

Comment: Have you tried to clean-install Chrome? Did you try incognito mode (where extensions are disabled)?

Comment: Didn't try a real from-scratch install yet, but that might be the only game in town. As my original question says, I tried incognito mode, and it has the same behaviour.

Comment: To rule out that yours is an installation problem, you can try another browser (try Firefox). Moreover, you can add another user, log in as this new user and try to connect with chrome and firefox. (In this case you can rule out that this is related to the user account settings). PS> have you tried with a mobile phone (again eg with Firefox) asking for a __Desktop site__ layout? Asking so you force the desktop version. You should rule out the case that they are currently only offering the mobile site version.

Comment: In chrome please try opening the "Developers Tools" (Ctrl + Shift + i), navigate to "Console" and type in "$0.offsetWidth" hit enter and the console will return a number. This will define what width the body is being displayed in. If this value is above 768 (this is the trigger in the CSS for the mobile website) then I think some of the website elements are not loading correctly. And this will likely be shown by errors in the console relating to the file SiteMasterATF.css. However if the value is less than this you will need to inspect chrome's extensions and settings.

Comment: @CarlNorum ... I was able to reproduce this for this site on a machine that was connected to a wifi connection and a VPN at the same time. Something funny was going on with DNS at the time it occurred though since I could not resolve DNS names on the network from the VPN which I was connected. This happened in both Chrome and Edge on this system. I connected via RDP to another machine on the local network connected to an Ethernet connection, and the page loaded just fine in Chrome. I tested from my Surface laptop connected to the same VPN and it loaded fine in Chrome.

Comment: @CarlNorum ... I rebooted the VPN connected machine with the funny behavior and now it works as expected. I'm not sure what the deal was exactly, but wanted to share since I too was able to reproduce this so perhaps it's related to a DNS issue. It is true websites are supposed to be programmed to recognize the browser that connects to the site and adjust the logic which that browser sees, but this is odd indeed and I experienced it too with only this site when I tried earlier and those are my finding and detail as FYI to you. Oh, and Firefox on the problem machine did the same thing too btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick idea: zoom out 10-20% from the menu bar.  That may fix the issue.  Sorry this answer is short.

Comment: This was the answer; that page was at 200% zoom. I have no idea how it got that way, but that is (apparently) a sticky setting in chrome.

Comment: Glad I could help! (Wait, does this mean I get the bounty?  Sorry, I’m still a little new to stack exchange )

Comment: Yes, indeed - enjoy!

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much!

Comment: I had gotten stuck on the mobile view of Stack Overflow apparently by zooming in with the touchpad for no better purpose than to see how large the font would draw. Well, yes, in order to escape from the mobile prison, the solution is to simply zoom out by hitting `Ctrl -` (minus) a couple times, or taking action from the menu as you described.

Comment: This solved it for me on Google Images! My zoom was at 100%, but zooming out to 80%, refreshing, and zooming back to 100% solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things I can think of :

- You can check ( following [this](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/change-user-agent/368448/) tutorial ) that you did not set a custom user agent for this site by mistake :
- You can try using ["user agent switcher" plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-and-m/bhchdcejhohfmigjafbampogmaanbfkg) to easily impersonate another browser /device with chrome ans see if the problem is still there
- It seems you have checked the viewport issue, but this might also another plugin setting your viewport depending on which plugins you have installed, you can check that you  don't have specific plugins allowed to run in private browsing as well.

Comment: No special user agent, nor does changing the user agent appear to do anything. I wonder what other things there are for me to clear out/delete.

Answer (score 0):

#### General answer.

In a case like yours you should rule out all hypotheses one by one until you find the solution (if it exists).

- Many sites act automatically by **providing a layout appropriate to the resolution of the connecting device**. Sometimes rearranging elements, other times, if you resize the window to less than a certain limit (chosen by the single site designer), they switch from computer to phone layout. Could this be your case? Is your browser windows big enough? (You may try to search for it in the code of the page and in the imported css files...)
- To rule out that yours is problem related with Chrome, you can try **another browser** (try Firefox).
- You can add **another user,** log in as this new user and try to connect with chrome and Firefox. In this case you can rule out that this is related to the user account settings, and to the cookies.
- You should rule out the case that they are currently **only offering the mobile site version**.  You may try with a mobile phone (again eg with Firefox) asking for a **Desktop site** layout. In this way you force the Desktop version of the site. You can switch back and see if there is any difference.
- Last, but not least, if you are connecting to a page via a login (possibly even automatic), the problem may be related to that **user's settings on that page**.

Unfortunately I have problem connecting to that site (time out errors) so I could not check it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only Chrome, perhaps a clean installation wouldn't suffer from this problem.

I suggest to uninstall Chrome (save the bookmarks), clear out all its folders,
then reinstall.

If then Chrome still has problems with this site, I suggest using a
Web debugging proxy to trace the exchange with this website.
Add the full trace to your post so we can analyze what's going wrong
(please in text format, not binary).

Answer (score 0):

The zoom OUT was super helpful, I have been trusted about this on one website I need to use, for some time and finally decided today was the day to fix it. This fix was super quick!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1106436)